# How to apply isinstance() on objects in a Python dictionary using a For loop

Tags: python, oop, for-loop

Is there a way to get a a quick `True`/`False` on whether I have any nested objects generated from the `ProjectTypeB` class from my below code?

```
class Project():
    def __init__(self):
        self.subProjects={}

    def addSubProject(self, child):
        child.parent=child
        self.subProjects[child.name]=child

class ProjectTypeA():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

class ProjectTypeB():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

#Create instances
a=Project()
a.addSubProject(ProjectTypeA("Project1"))
a.addSubProject(ProjectTypeB("Project2"))
```

From this, I am trying to find a way to check if any of the objects in `a.subProjects` are instantiated from the class `ProjectTypeB` (for example). I have tried things along the lines of the below but with no luck:

```
class Project():
    #... 

    def ProjectTypeB_Specific(self):
        with p in self.subProjects:
            if isinstance(p, ProjectTypeB):
                # Rest of code...
```

Comment: `with p in self.subProjects:` ? do you mean `for p in self.subProjects:`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out - I won't 'fix' the code in my question though as it will just confuse future readers...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way to do this is via `any` with a generator expression:

```
return any(isinstance(p, ProjectTypeB) for p in self.subProjects)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks ideal - although I tried the following it with the following but just get FALSE returned (excuse lack of carriage returns!): `if any(isinstance(p, ProjectTypeB) for p in self.subProjects): print "TRUE" else: print "FALSE"`....any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: trying to print `p` it returns `NameError: global name 'p' is not defined`...but `p` isn't a `self.p` either though is it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iterate over it using a looping construct such as `for` instead of `with`. `with` is intended for context managers, which have a very different usecase.

```
for p in self.subProjects
    if isinstance(p, ProjectTypeB):
        # rest of code
```